# runSaga not working when yield call in Saga has action parameter

Tags: react-native, jestjs, redux-saga

I am using Jest to create unit test on my React project that uses redux-saga.

This is my saga code block

```
export function* getDataSaga(action) {
  try {
    const data = yield call(http.getData, action.params);
    console.log('Hello')
    yield put({
      type: actionTypes.LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS,
      data: data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({
      type: actionTypes.LOAD_DATA_FAILED,
    });
  }
}
```

And this is my unit test

```
import { runSaga } from 'redux-saga'
import http from '../../../http';
import { getDataSaga } from '../data'

describe('getDataSaga', () => {
    
    it('should call api and dispatch success action', async () => {
        const dummyData = {name : "Data 1"};
        const requestData = jest.spyOn(http, "getData").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(dummyData));
    
        const dispatched = [];
    
        const result = await runSaga({
            dispatch : (action) => dispatched.push(action),
        }, getDataSaga);

       
        const expectedAction = {Data : {name: "Data 1"},type: "LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS"};
    
        expect(requestData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

        expect(dispatched).toEqual([expectedAction]);
        requestData.mockClear();
    })

});
```

My issue is that when I remove action.param on below code, runSaga works as expected and getDataSaga is executed, but not if  I put it back.

`const data = yield call(http.getData, action.params);`
change to
`const data = yield call(http.getData);`

I think this [https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/48](http://issue) is connected but I still cannot find any solution.

Comment: Do you not have to say which action is to be dispatched, I meant 
in  const result = await runSaga({
            dispatch : (action) => dispatched.push(action),
        }, getDataSaga);
should it not be 
 const result = await runSaga({
            dispatch : (action) => dispatched.push(action),
        }, getDataSaga, actionToDispatch);

Comment: You are right! I added a mock object as 3rd param and it worked. I can't believe how long I have tried to solve this. Thanks a lot :)